# how left outer join works for table have null values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have four tables: `person` and `booking`, booking_detail,room_pricing where `person_id` used as foreign key in the `booking` table and `person_id` is used as foreign key in the `booking_detail` table. where room_id is used as foreign_key in booking_detail

Supposing I want to show all the `booking_id` from `booking` table and their corresponding total income from rooms on each booking including those who doesn't exist in `` table such as `id 1` ,i am using oracle database

#### person

```
person_id      name
        1      xyz
        2      abc
        3      jkl
```

#### booking

```
booking_id     person_id
        1          1
        2          3
        3          1
```

#### booking_details

```
person_id     roomid
        2     201
        3     303
        3     303
```

#### room_pricing

```
room_id       price
   201       $ 100
   302       $ 100
   303       $ 200
```

final table should be like this

```
    booking_id    total
    1              0
    2            400$
    3             0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following using `left join`

```
select
  b.booking_id,
  coalesce(sum(total), 0) as total
from booking b

left join booking_details bd
on b.person_id = bd.person_id

left join room_pricing rp
on bd.room_id = rp.room_id

group by
  b.booking_id
```

Comment: i tried it but its doesnt work for me as i have multiple table,i make some changes in the question please review

Answer (score 0):

You want a `left join` with aggregation:

```
select p.person_id, coalesce(sum(o.total), 0)
from person p left join
     order o
     on o.person_id = p.person_id
group by p.person_id;
```